# How to use xbox one controller in C# application

Tags: c#, sharpdx

There already exists a large amount of information for using an xbox 360 controller in C#, but I didn't find as much info for an xbox one controller.

I need very basic operation out of it, specifically the joystick and trigger values.

The majority of information online is for C++ applications, but rather than attempting to write a custom library, I'd like to use something like [SharpDX](http://sharpdx.org/). How do I use this in my application?

Note: I'm posting this to share info that I found, as well as documenting my findings for myself. I'd love to hear other methods of getting controller input into a .NET application though.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The easiest way I found to get started was to use SharpDX. From the [SharpDX website](http://sharpdx.org/):

> SharpDX is an open-source managed .NET wrapper of the DirectX API.

[SharpDX is available on nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SharpDX/), so it's very simple to get started with it inside Visual Studios.

To get started, go to `Tools -> NuGet Package Manager -> Package Manager Console` inside Visual Studios (I'm using 2015 community edition).

[image: Adding sharpdx with package manager inside VS2015]

Then simply type: `Install-Package SharpDX` into the Package Manager Console that appears at the bottom of Visual Studios.

[image: Install SharpDX]

Visual Studios will then download and add it to your solution. Now onto the code.

Since I wanted input from the xbox controller, we just need to add:
`using SharpDX.XInput` to the top of our program.

And the code to get all the values is fairly simple:

```
class XInputController
{
    Controller controller;
    Gamepad gamepad;
    public bool connected = false;
    public int deadband = 2500;
    public Point leftThumb, rightThumb = new Point(0,0);
    public float leftTrigger, rightTrigger;

    public XInputController()
    {
        controller = new Controller(UserIndex.One);
        connected = controller.IsConnected;
    }

    // Call this method to update all class values
    public void Update()
    {
        if(!connected) 
            return;

        gamepad = controller.GetState().Gamepad;

        leftThumb.x  = (Math.Abs((float)gamepad.LeftThumbX ) < deadband) ?  0 : (float)gamepad.LeftThumbX  / short.MinValue * -100;
        leftThumb.y  = (Math.Abs((float)gamepad.LeftThumbY ) < deadband) ?  0 : (float)gamepad.LeftThumbY  / short.MaxValue * 100;
        rightThumb.y = (Math.Abs((float)gamepad.RightThumbX) < deadband) ?  0 : (float)gamepad.RightThumbX / short.MaxValue * 100;
        rightThumb.x = (Math.Abs((float)gamepad.RightThumbY) < deadband) ?  0 : (float)gamepad.RightThumbY / short.MaxValue * 100;

        leftTrigger  = gamepad.LeftTrigger;
        rightTrigger =  gamepad.RightTrigger;
    }
}
```

This creates a deadband because the joysticks on the controller never fully return to zero. It also inverts the left X axis so that both stick inputs match. Y positive is up, X positive is to the right:

```
leftThumb.x  = (Math.Abs((float)gamepad.LeftThumbX ) < deadband) ?  0 : (float)gamepad.LeftThumbX  / short.MinValue * -100;
leftThumb.y  = (Math.Abs((float)gamepad.LeftThumbY ) < deadband) ?  0 : (float)gamepad.LeftThumbY  / short.MaxValue * 100;
rightThumb.y = (Math.Abs((float)gamepad.RightThumbX) < deadband) ?  0 : (float)gamepad.RightThumbX / short.MaxValue * 100;
rightThumb.x = (Math.Abs((float)gamepad.RightThumbY) < deadband) ?  0 : (float)gamepad.RightThumbY / short.MaxValue * 100;
```

Hopefully this will be helpful to someone in the future looking to add an xbox one controller input to their .NET application!

Comment: +1 An alternative lightweight is https://github.com/speps/XInputDotNet and for deadzones you probably want to do this instead https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee417001(v=vs.85).aspx#dead_zone

Comment: Thanks for the additional info! @Aybe I'll have to give XInputDotNet a look! I had to decrease my polling rate to the controller to about 100mhz( 10ms of delay) because it was kicking off the garbage collector every 2 seconds at max polling. No noticeable difference at a 10ms poll rate.

Comment: This is out of date now and does not work.