# How to control an IP camera with a joystick without spamming messages?

Tags: design-patterns, ip-camera, joystick

I'd like a recommandation on how to approach the problem I'm facing as a software developer.

**Context:**

I have an IP Camera that can be moved with a PTZ (Pan, Tilt, Zoom) command that can be called like so:

`PTZ(float pan, float tilt, float zoom)`

I have a joystick that update its input values every ~0.0001 sec and the available input values are:

- `joystickX`: from -1(left) to 1(right) 0 being the center
- `joystickY`: from -1(down) to 1(up) 0 being the center
- `joystickMagnitude`: from 0(untouched) to 1(completely pushed)
- `zoomButton+`: pressed(`zoomValue` = 1) or not
- `zoomButton-`: pressed(`zoomValue` = -1) or not

Right now, every time the joystick values are updated, a message to the camera is sent, so it's kinda spamming the camera every ~0.0001 sec with `PTZ` messages.

Ex:

- Joystick input value update
- `PTZ(joystickX*joystickMagnitude, joystickY*joystickMagnitude, zoomValue)` message sent
- Repeat in ~0.0001 sec

**Question:**

What would be the best approach to be able to control the camera with the joystick without spamming `PTZ` messages?

Here's what I have so far:

(Note that this is based on)

- [How to use xbox one controller in C# application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39109609/how-to-use-xbox-one-controller-in-c-sharp-application)
- https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/67651/what-is-the-standard-c-windows-forms-game-loop

So yeah

```
private void ConnectXboxController()
{
    _xboxController = new XInputController();
    if (_xboxController.Connected)
    {
        //set the update/render loop
        Application.Idle += HandleApplicationIdle;
        MessageBox.Show("The controller has been connected.");
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("The controller could not be connected.");
    }
}

private void DisconnectXboxController()
{
    _xboxController = null;
    Application.Idle -= HandleApplicationIdle;
    MessageBox.Show("The controller has been disconnected.");
}

private void Update()
{
    //Update xbox controller properties

    if (!_xboxController.Update())
    {
        //Stop the loop
        DisconnectXboxController();
    }
}

private void Render()
{
    //Render changes made to the xbox controller properties
    try
    {
        if (_xboxController.LeftThumb.Magnitude != 0)
        {
            _moving = true;
            _camera.PostPTZContinuous(
                _xboxController.LeftThumb.Direction.X * _xboxController.LeftThumb.Magnitude * _camera.Speed,
                _xboxController.LeftThumb.Direction.Y * _xboxController.LeftThumb.Magnitude * _camera.Speed,
                0);
        }
        else
        {
            if (_moving == true)
            {
                _camera.PostPTZContinuous(0, 0, 0);
                _moving = false;
                UpdateCurrentStatus();
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception) { }
}

private bool IsApplicationIdle()
{
    NativeMessage result;
    return PeekMessage(out result, IntPtr.Zero, (uint)0, (uint)0, (uint)0) == 0;
}

private void HandleApplicationIdle(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Stops when the xbox controller is set to null
    while (IsApplicationIdle() && _xboxController != null)
    {
        Update();
        Render();
    }
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct NativeMessage
{
    public IntPtr Handle;
    public uint Message;
    public IntPtr WParameter;
    public IntPtr LParameter;
    public uint Time;
    public Point Location;
}

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern int PeekMessage(out NativeMessage message, IntPtr window, uint filterMin, uint filterMax, uint remove);
```

Comment: Rate-limit the messages.

Comment: @Dai Won't that affect the responsivity of the inputs too much? Like the time between an input and the movement. And what if the limited message is a message telling the camera to stop itself from moving? It'll just make the camera go in a direction without ever ending.

Comment: Just store the current values in global variables and check in PTZ function for any updated values. Can you share the function on which you are working on?

Comment: @AkashBadam Sure (: And thanks for the idea